# I'm attempting to create a small GUI application, but the contents of the JFrame are not showing on screen. How can I fix my code?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

As of late I've been developing a (very) small GUI application in Java. I'm extremely new to Swing and Java in general, but up until now I have been able to get everything to work the way I want it to. However, after cleaning up my code, when I run the program nothing but the border of the window appears. What am I doing wrong and how can I fix my code? Thanks ahead of time!

*For the sake of saving space I've made Pastebin links to all of my classes (besides Main).*

**Main Class**

```
package me.n3rdfall.ezserver.main;

public class Main {

    public static GUI g = new GUI();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        g.showWindow(800, 500);

    }

}
```

**GUI Class**

http://pastebin.com/gDMipdp1

**ButtonListener Class**

http://pastebin.com/4XXm70AD

EDIT: It appears that calling removeAll() directly on 'frame' actually removed essential things other than what I had added. By calling removeAll() on getContentPane(), the issue was resolved.

Comment: Show your code in the question instead of pasting them to some sort of pastebin.

Comment: I use Pastebin links because the other two classes were quite long. If that doesn't matter, then in the future I will simply paste the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick hack: Remove the `removeAll()` functions.

```
public void homePage() {
//      frame.removeAll();
//      mainpanel.removeAll();
//      topbar.removeAll();
```

I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve, but that will at least show some items. If I were you I would rebuild this GUI by extending JFrame. It will make your code a little easier to read.

I also think what you are trying to achieve with the buttons is to switch layouts, you can do this in an easier way by using `CardLayout`

Example (has nothing to do with your code, but to demonstrate):

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Example extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    private JButton leftButton;
    private JButton rightButton;

    private CardLayout cardLayout = new CardLayout();
    JPanel cards = new JPanel(cardLayout);
    final static String LEFTPANEL = "LEFTPANEL";
    final static String RIGHTPANEL = "RIGHTPANEL";
    JPanel card1;
    JPanel card2;

    public Example()    {
        JPanel topPanel = new JPanel();
        addButtons(topPanel);

        add(topPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(cards, BorderLayout.CENTER);

     //Initiates the card panels

        initCards();

        setTitle("My Window");
        setSize(300, 300);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    private void initCards() {
        card1 = new JPanel();
        card2 = new JPanel();
        card1.setBackground(Color.black);
        card2.setBackground(Color.red);

        cards.add(card1, LEFTPANEL);
        cards.add(card2, RIGHTPANEL);
    }

    private void addButtons(Container con)  {
        leftButton = new JButton("Left Button");
        leftButton.addActionListener(this);
        rightButton = new JButton("Right Button");
        rightButton.addActionListener(this);

        con.add(leftButton, BorderLayout.WEST);
        con.add(rightButton, BorderLayout.EAST);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(e.getSource().equals(leftButton))    {
            //Change cardlayout
            cardLayout.show(cards, LEFTPANEL);      
        } else if(e.getSource().equals(rightButton))    {
            //Change cardlayout
            cardLayout.show(cards, RIGHTPANEL);     
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Example();
    }

}
```